# How can I return the key of the last item in an array matching a value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How do you recommend fetching the key of the last matching value in an array?

```
$arr = array(
     0 => 0,
     1 => 1,
     2 => 2,
     3 => 3,
     4 => 4,
     5 => 5,
     6 => 5,
     7 => 5,
     8 => 5,
     9 => 5, // <--- this is the key I'm after!
    10 => 6,
    11 => 7,
    12 => 8,
    13 => 9,
    14 => 10,
    15 => 11);

function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
    // return 9
}

echo returnLastMatching($arr,5);  // "9"
```

Comment: Can you show us the content you tried in your `returnLastMatching` ?

Comment: iterate from the end and find first matching element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$last_key = -1;
$foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == $needle) {
        $last_key = $key;
    }
}
```

Each time the value = the needle it will overwrite the last element and save the key, in the end you will have the last occurrence.

== As Bora suggested ==

```
function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
    return array_pop(array_keys($haystack, $needle));
}
```

Comment: Why `$last_key` is an array?

Comment: Why 0 is the first value , change it to -1 or false or something that will be understood like value is not found , 0 is an existing element

Comment: @FaceOfJock Noted i ll edit it and include Bora's answer since i loved it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one with `array_pop` and `array_keys`

```
function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
    return array_pop(array_keys($haystack, $needle));
}
```

### Process

#### get keys with array_keys

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 5
  1 => int 6
  2 => int 7
  3 => int 8
  4 => int 9
```

#### get last element with array_pop

```
9
```

Comment: nice, did not know that `array_keys` has that second parameter!

Answer (score 1):

[The foreach construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) has 2 possible signatures, one of which will also give you the key value of the current element:

```
function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
    foreach (array_reverse($haystack) as $k => $val) 
        if ($val == $needle) return $k;
    // instead of
    // foreach ($haystack as $val)...
}
```

To get the last element, the [`array_reverse`](http://www.php.net/array_reverse) call is added while passing the array to foreach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would simply return "5".

Comment: I'm sure this will return the first match.

Comment: Watch your code typo. Being the FGITW doesn't make your code run properly. Did you even try it?

Answer (score 1):

```
function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
    return array_pop(array_keys($haystack, $needle));
}
```

Comment: this solution will return array without the last element

Answer (score 1):

### FIRST SOLUTION:

This solution using  `array_search()` and `array_reverse()` , you first reverse your array and then take the first key that matchs your needle:

```
function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
  return   array_search($needle,array_reverse($haystack, true));
}
```

### SECONDE SOLUTION:

Use `array_keys()` to get all keys that match your needle , and then get the last element from this array of keys:

```
   function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {

      return end(array_keys( $haystack, $needle));
  }
```

Comment: Returns first key not last.

Comment: Nice one with end(), just add missing paren :)

Comment: First one: PHP Warning:  array_search() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Answer (score 1):

```
$lastkey = false;
foreach($haystick as $key => $val) {
    if($val === $needle) $lastkey = $key;
}
return $lastkey;
```

This will iterate to the end of the haystick, thus returning the last key if there is at least one, or false if there is none.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_keys`

```
$keys = array_keys($arr, 5); //will return all matched keys
echo end($keys); //will output the last key it was matched with
```

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work:

```
    function returnLastMatching($haystack,$needle) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$element)
    {



        if($element==$needle)
        {
            $temp=$key;
        }

    }
      return $temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change `echo returnLastMatching($arr,5);` with

```
$arr = array_flip($arr);
echo $arr[5];
```

No need to use function we can get the result